# Javascript Eval overwriting variable

Tags: javascript, eval

Don't understand why the code below is overwriting my var arr. Any help appreciated.

```
var arr = [1,2,3]

var string = "function swap(arr) { var newarr = arr; var temp = arr[0]; newarr[0] = arr[arr.length-1]; newarr[arr.length-1] = temp; return newarr }"

var test = eval("[" + string + "]")[0];

test(arr);
console.log(arr);
//this outputs [3,2,1]

test(arr);
console.log(arr);
//this outputs [1,2,3]
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pccse/2br13m71/)

Thanks

Comment: `newarr = arr;` means that `newarr` points to the same exact object as `arr`. So anything you do to `newarr` will be reflected in `arr` as well. You want `newarr = arr.slice()` to make a copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in JavaScript, objects are pass by reference value and arrays are objects. The eval is irrelevant here. Here is code producing the same issue without eval:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = arr; // this just sets the reference
arr2[1] = 3; // this also changes arr
arr[0] = 3; // this also changes arr2
arr; // [3, 3, 3]
arr2; // [3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Why does this happen

JavaScript kind of has a thing where it creates *references* instead of copies. This can be useful, and annoying:

> *Where is it useful?*

```
var self = this;
```

is a commonly used trick to trap the scope of a function.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('my_element');
```

is a way refer to elements as variables

### When does this happen?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var arr2 = arr;    //arr2 now references arr
var arr2[1] = 'd'; //Modifies arr2 and reference

console.log(arr2); //Line 6
console.log(arr);  //Line 7
```

This will give us:

> [1, 'd', 3, 4] (line 6)
>
> [1, 'd', 3, 4] (line 7)

In conclusion, this is just regular behavior of JavaScript!

### What should I do?

To solve this, add

```
var arr2 = arr.slice();
```

`.slice()` returns a *new* version of the array. You can write your own function to do this by:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function () {
    return this.slice();
}
```

Now we can do:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var arr2 = arr.clone(); //  Returns cloned arr
var arr2[1] = 'd';      //  Modifies arr2

console.log(arr2); //Line 6
console.log(arr);  //Line 7
```

This time:

> [1, 'd', 3, 4] (line 6)
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4]   (line 7)

Comment: `var arr2 = arr;` does not **create** a reference - `arr` already *is* a reference.

Comment: @Pointy Ah yes, I see how that doesn't make sense

Comment: Adding things to `Array.prototype` (or `Object.prototype` for that matter) in this way will cause problems if you try to iterate through an array later. You should use `Object.defineProperty` to make it non-enumerable.