# OO Javascript copy of object

Tags: javascript

I have a question about how javascript copies objects with the below sample code:

```
var blue = {a:1};
var yellow = blue
yellow = 3;
```

In this case, blue's value would be unaffected as an object with a=1. However, when written like this:

```
var blue = {a:1};
blue.b = 2;
var yellow = blue
yellow.c = 3;`
```

in this case, console.log(blue) would show blue also having an extra {c:3} in it's object. How is the variable blue getting affected by yellow when the `yellow = blue` should be just yellow referencing blue and not vice versa?

Comment: That's because `yellow` is set to a "reference" of blue. You don't change blue, you change the value from a reference, to another value. I've written about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29871978/1620622)

Comment: You can't natively "copy" objects in JavaScript. They are *similar* to pointers in languages like C++.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted so much. It seems like an innocent misunderstanding of how javascript works.

Comment: This shows a complete lack of research.

Comment: @Kith Another quick search on Google gives [another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript) that explains how assignments work.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess that makes sense. But honestly, I don't think steve would have known to google for the words "by reference" or "by value". A lot of times I find answers to questions through these differently worded duplicates. Case in point, that "duplicate" answer that is cited now at the top of the post is, itself, a duplicate lol

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. You are right Kith, i have no idea what proper word for the concepts I'm asking here are since I just learned it today through trial and error. I'm now learning they are called pass by value/reference as a result of asking here. Down or up votes kinda doesn't matter to me lol. I learned from asking, that's all it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, all assignments are done by value.

However, in the case of objects, that value is a reference.

That is, if you use `yellow = blue`, both `yellow` and `blue` will contain the same object in memory. So you can't alter one without modifying the other one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
var blue = {a:1};
var yellow = blue;   // yellow references blue...

yellow = 3;          // but not anymore. Now it's just a number.
```

In the second:

```
var blue = {a:1};
blue.b = 2;

var yellow = blue    // yellow references blue
yellow.c = 3;        // and still does, so yellow.c and blue.c are the same`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a value to a variable, whatever value that variable had before is gone. That's what happens in your first sample.

When you assign a variable to a value that is an object, and you then modify that object (setting a property of it to some value), you still have that variable pointing that object. That's what happens in your second sample.

The other thing that happens in your second sample is that `blue` & `yellow` point to the same object, so modifying via `blue` is identical to modifying via `yellow`, and in both cases the effect "applies" to both variables (it's always the same object)